# How to select distinct records from two tables, combine into one column, and eliminate all records that exist in another table using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, join, distinct, union

Here is my existing query which successfully selects distinct records from two tables and combines them into one column:

```
SELECT index_text AS unique_text FROM words
UNION
SELECT c1index_text FROM words_content 
ORDER BY unique_text
```

Now I want to eliminate all records `WHERE body NOT IN (SELECT body FROM sms)` (or `NOT EXISTS`, whatever works is fine). The problem is that no matter what I try, either I get a syntax error whenever I attempt to use parentheses, or it will not recognize `sms.body` (even if I precede every column by its parent table). I'm thinking some SQLite limitations may be making this harder than it needs to be, but there has to be a workaround. **Below are queries I have tried unsuccessfully** (I have also tried numerous variations of these queries to no avail):

```
SELECT index_text AS unique_text FROM words
UNION
SELECT c1index_text FROM words_content
  WHERE body NOT IN (SELECT body FROM sms)
ORDER BY unique_text
```

Results in error: `No such column: body`

```
SELECT words.index_text AS unique_text FROM words
UNION
SELECT words_content.c1index_text FROM words_content
LEFT JOIN sms
  ON sms.body=unique_text
ORDER BY unique_text
```

Results in error: `No such column: unique_text`

How do I join to an alias column and show only records that do not exist in `sms.body`? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use where or join clauses in UNIONs you have to apply them to both [select](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) statements.

```
SELECT index_text AS unique_text 
FROM words
where index_text NOT IN (SELECT body FROM sms)
UNION
SELECT c1index_text 
FROM words_content
WHERE c1index_text NOT IN (SELECT body FROM sms)
ORDER BY unique_text
```